# Show last string when input value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML block

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#q1">
     Question 1
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="q1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputQ1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputQ1" placeholder="e.g How was our service?">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the Jquery

```
$('.panel-body input').keyup(function () {
    $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').prev('.panel-heading').find('a').text(this.value);
});
```

Basically what this does is that whatever the user types in the input box, it will be displayed in the anchor tag.

Now, the problem I'm facing is that when the user types something and decides to delete the content in the input box, then the anchor tag will no longer have content. Ideally it should always show the previous content whenever the input box is focused. I hope my description of the problem is clear enough ...

Here's a link to JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SpLsZ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have update your fiddle, check: http://jsfiddle.net/SpLsZ/2/

I put a data variable `value` in your anchor tag. When your text content is changing, I'm now checking if it has a value or not. If it is not, I'm retrieving data `value` and inserting it as text value.

```
<a href="#q1" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-parent="#accordion" 
    data-value="Question 1"
>Question 1</a>
```

```js
$('.panel-body input').keyup(function () {
   var header = $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').prev('.panel-heading').find('a');

   if(this.value == "") {
      header.text(header.data("value"));
   } else {
      header.text(this.value);
   }
});
```

Comment: @Anton I didn' think about shorting code in those lines, I was focused on data value, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Anton Even shorter : `header.text(this.value || header.data("value"))`.

Comment: @procrastinator ah true that :)

Comment: Thanks! I've learned something new :) Didn't thought about using data value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.panel-body input').keyup(function () {
    $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').prev('.panel-heading').find('a').text(
        this.value || 'Question 1'
    );
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpLsZ/1/)**

Comment: If it is Question 2??

Comment: There are many ways to make this work. OP can store the value as an attribute and restore it from there.

Comment: Yup I know it, but the same I wanted you to edit in your answer so i pointed it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpLsZ/4/

Change you HTML markup like so:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#q1">
    <span class="question">Question 1</span>
    <span class="answer"></span>
</a>
```

This way you don't have to worry about storing any values.
And your JavaScript to:

```
$('.panel-body input').keyup(function () {
    var $link = $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').prev('.panel-heading').find('a');
    var $question = $link.find('.question');
    var $answer = $link.find('.answer');

    if (this.value) {
        $question.hide();
        $answer.text(this.value);
    } else {
        $question.show();
        $answer.empty();
    }
});
```

When you have any value you hide the qestion text and show the answer, if no value is entered show question and empty answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.panel-body input').keyup(function () {
    $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').prev('.panel-heading').find('a').text(this.value);
}).blur(function () {
    if ($.trim(this.value) == '') {
        $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').prev('.panel-heading').find('a').text(function () {
            return $(this).data('default')
        });
    }
});
$('.panel-heading a').each(function () {
    $(this).data('default', $(this).text());
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U66t7/)